# Multiple URLs opened when selecting one subitem

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am writing a Chrome extension to help navigate a difficult website. So far I managed to run a small JS via browser action and created a submenu for URLs to the bits I use the most on the website.

On selecting any of the three subitems, Chrome opens three new tabs each with one of the URLs in the submenu. Any idea how to improve this?

I started learning this 3 days ago, so apologies if question is a duplicate.

manifest.json

```
{
"name": "Satisfactory",
"version": "1.0",
"manifest_version": 2,
"author": "Mohamed Aly",
"description": "Features they should have on ISCP",
"incognito": "split",
"icons":{
    "128":"icon.png"
},
"background": {
  "scripts": ["background.js"],
  "persistent": false
},
"permissions": ["tabs", "contextMenus"],
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": [
      "https://www.iscp.ac.uk/*"
    ],
    "js": ["content.js"]
  }
],
"browser_action": {
  "default_icon": "icon.png",
  "default_title": "All is satisfactory!"
}  
}
```

```js
// background.js

console.log('Satisfactory is running in the background!')

// Called when the user clicks on the browser action.
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(buttonClicked);

function buttonClicked(tab) {

  console.log("button clicked!");

  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {"message": "browser action"});
}
//Listening for messages
// chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(receiver);

// function receiver(request, sender, sendResponse) {
//   if (request.message === "thank you") {
//   }
// }
//context menu:
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
  console.log("context menus added");

  var parent = chrome.contextMenus.create({
    "title": "Satisfactory", 
    "id": "parent",
    "contexts": ["all"]
  });

  var child1 = chrome.contextMenus.create(
    {"title": "Work in progress", 
    "parentId": parent, 
    "id": "workinProgress",
    "contexts": ["all"]
  });
    
  var child2 = chrome.contextMenus.create(
    {"title": "Add a CBD", 
    "parentId": parent, 
    "id": "addaCBD",
    "contexts": ["all"]
  });

  var child2 = chrome.contextMenus.create(
    {"title": "Add a PBA", 
    "parentId": parent, 
    "id": "addaPBA",
    "contexts": ["all"]
  });
});
///Work in progress option
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(workinProgress);

    function workinProgress(tabs) {
      console.log("WIP clicked!");
      open('https://www.iscp.ac.uk/dash/work_in_progress_list.aspx')
    };

//Add a CBD option
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(addaCBD);

    function addaCBD(tabs) {
      console.log("CBD clicked!");
      open('https://www.iscp.ac.uk/forms/cbd.aspx')
    };

//Add a PBA option
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(addaPBA);

    function addaPBA(tabs) {
      console.log("PBA clicked!");
      open('https://www.iscp.ac.uk/forms/PBA.aspx')
    };
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Simply join all onClicked functions into one that checks the first parameter's `info.menuItemId` and switches what to do based on that. Make sure to check the  documentation for the exact parameters of each API method you're using or set up DefinitelyTyped for chrome API in your IDE so it will autocomplete and show parameter hints for you. See also [samples](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#search:contextMenus).